# Mongodb - Fetch distinct values from a collection using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

How to fetch and display only the distinct values of a key for all elements using PHP.
In my application I am already fetching data using the below code and assigning that data to an array which will be further used in JS.

```
<?php
require 'C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\vendor\autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->test->bf;
$clubSelectList = array();

$clubSelectListResult = $collection->find();

foreach ($clubSelectListResult as $option) {
    echo $option['club'], "<br><br>";
}

?>
```

How can I fetch unique values. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**
This does it.

```
$clubSelectListResult = $collection->distinct('club');

foreach ($clubSelectListResult as $option) {
    echo $option, "<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `distinct` method:

```
$collection->distinct('your_distinct_field');
```